# Knowing which sets of topological partition $\mathcal{P}$ are visited by an iteration of an homeomorphism $\phi$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

**Definition** A topological partition of a metric space $M$ is a finite collection $\mathcal{P} = \{ P_0,\cdots , P_{r-1}\}$ of disjoint open sets whose closures $\overline{P_{j}}$ together cover $M$ in the sense that $M = \overline{P_{0}}\text{ }\cup \cdots \cup \overline{P_{r-1}}$.

Suppose that $(M,\phi)$ is a non invertible dynamical system (i.e  M  a metric space and  $\phi : M \to M$ continuous). Let $\mathcal{A} = \{0,\cdots ,r-1 \}$. We say that a word $w = a_{1} \cdots a_{n}$, where $a_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$, is allowed for $\mathcal{P},\phi$  if $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} \phi^{-j}(P_{a_{j}}) \neq \emptyset$.

I'm trying to prove that if $w = a_{1} \cdots a_{n}$, is allowed for $\mathcal{P},\phi$. then there exist $t\in\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$
\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n} \phi^{-j}(P_{w_{j}}) \right ) \cap \phi^{-(n+1)}(P_{t}) \neq \emptyset
$$
What I have so far; There is $x \in \cap_{j=1}^{n} \phi^{-j}(P_{w_{j}}) $, observed that the intersection is not empty and open, so there exists $\delta >0$ such that $B(x,\delta) \subseteq \cap_{j=1}^{n} \phi^{-j}(P_{w_{j}})$. on the other hand, if we look where $\phi^{n+1}(x)$ land, because $\mathcal{P}$ is a topological partition, there exist $t\in\mathcal{A}$. such that $\phi^{n+1}(x) \in \overline{P_{t}}$. the hard case occur when $\phi^{n+1}(x) \in \partial P_{t}$. In that case we know that for all $\varepsilon > 0$
$B(\phi^{n+1}(x), \varepsilon) \cap P_{t} \neq \emptyset$. and here is where I got stuck. maybe the idea is to find another point $y\in X$ using continuity of $\phi$ or powers $\phi$